# Invalid procedure call or argument on Replace function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to automate copying HMTL table then allocate the data into selected cells, but an error occurs upon Replacing certain data on a column, upon clicking debug the code works but it doesn't continue to deleting the cells.

Error:

[image: error]

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Button11_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim j As Integer, b As Integer, r As Integer, g As String

Range("XET1").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True

j = 6
b = 1

For r = 5 To 1000
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 5).Value <> "" Then

        Range("C" & j).Value = Range("XEU" & b).Value
        g = Range("XEV" & b)
        Range("E" & j).Value = Replace(Mid(g, InStr(g, "(") + 5, InStr(g, ")") - InStr(g, "(") - 5), "CEST", "")
        Range("D" & j).Value = Replace(Mid(g, InStr(g, "") + 38, InStr(g, ")") - InStr(g, "(") + 25), "REQ", "")
        Range("F" & j).Value = Range("XFD" & b).Value

    j = j + 1
    b = b + 1
   End If
Next r

ActiveSheet.Range("XET1:XFD50").Clear
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what line causes the error, and what string is in variable "g" (can you show some sample strings - most probably some of those string don't contain "(" or ")" or Mid is not extracting them as you expect)

Comment: This line causes the error `Range("E" & j).Value = Replace(Mid(g, InStr(g, "(") + 5, InStr(g, ")") - InStr(g, "(") - 5), "CEST", "")`

Answer (score 1):

Without the data to hand I can't say for sure, but I strongly suspect the problem is that one or more of your `InStr` checks are returning 0, meaning that the characters you're searching for ("(" and ")") aren't in the string. This means that you're calling `Mid(g,0,0)`, which causes the error you've reported.

I suggest that you check for the presence of the character you're searching for before you try to replace it, thus:

```
If InStr(1, g, ")") > 0 Then
    'your replace code here
Else
    Debug.Print ("Search character not found")
End If
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it works.